# Simple harmonic motion equation equivalence

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My textbook covered simple harmonic motion and gave the equation $y = A\sin{(\omega t)}$
Later it gave the equation $y = A\sin \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x-vt)$. I believe that these two equations are equivalent.  The first equation should represent x = 0, but if I plug that in, I don't recover $y = A\sin{(\omega t)}$

Simply put, how do I convert $y = A\sin \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x-vt)$ to $y = A\sin{(\omega t)}$ and vice versa, where A = amplitude, $\lambda$ = wavelength, $\omega=$ angular velocity etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First see how the rotation angle $\theta=\omega \cdot t$ can be converted.

$$ \omega= \frac{2 \pi}{T}=2 \pi f \,;$$

$$ x= v\cdot t\,, t=\frac{x}{v}, \, $$

$$\rightarrow \theta= \omega \, t= \frac{2 \pi\,f\,x}{v};$$

But $$ \frac{v}{f}= \lambda,\frac{f}{v}=\,\frac{1}{ \lambda}$$

Plug in

$$\rightarrow \theta= \frac{2 \pi\,x}{\lambda};$$

Phase shift $\phi$ is a fraction of one full rotation $ 2 \pi$

$$ \phi = 2 \pi \cdot \frac{t}{T} = \frac{ 2 \pi v t}{\lambda} $$

Plug in and finally

$$ y= A \sin\left ( \omega t - \phi \right)=A \sin   \frac{2 \pi (x-vt)}{\lambda} $$

Comment: With regards to the period and wavelength, my textbook also stated that "Usually $\lambda$ is called the wavelength, but mathematically it is the same as the period T..."  I noticed that in your calculation, the period is $T=\frac{\lambda}{v}$ so does this mean that T is not the same as $\lambda$?

Comment: One needs to understand distinctly whether we are talking about time domain or distance travelled domain. Both are values for one wave. The former has a time period $T$ and the latter has a wavelength $\lambda$. Also $ v= \frac{\lambda}{T}$.

Answer (score 0):

when $x=0$ you have
$$ y = A\sin\left(-2\pi \frac{v}{\lambda}t\right) = A\sin \left(2\pi\frac{v}{\lambda}t + \pi\right) $$

They're similar but not quite equivalent as there's an added phase. You do, however, get $\omega = 2\pi\dfrac{v}{\lambda}$